# Domain Access Login Redirect for main domain and subdomain

Tags: rules, users, redirection, domain-access

I have created three sites namely one.example.com, two.example.com, three.example.com using domain access. Here one.example.com is the main site which can create n number of subdomains. I want to redirect the admin of one.example.com to the dashboard and the other two to their respective content listing page. I'm using rules to redirect the admin of one.example.com to the dashboard. But when i login from the two.example.com, it also redirect to the dashboard which returns a "Access denied" page. How to set login redirect separately for subdomains. Please Help. I'm struck!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by creating two different roles and by adding a condition for "User has roles". So admin for one.example.com and sub-admin for two.example.com and three.example.com. Currently it works greats according to the condition. But is there any way to set the rules for same role with different actions?